# Import image in MATLAB from phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, database, matlab

I want to read an image file in MATLAB that is present in MySQL database, say phpMyAdmin.

Comment: If a provided answer helped you, you can mark it as accepted (on the left side next to the answer). The responder will get a reward in form of reputation points.

Answer (score 0):

Check the function [`database`](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/database/ug/database.html). You need to have the access credentials. Next, you can create an sql query.

```
datasource = "";
username = "yourUsername";
password = "password";

conn = database(datasource,username,password);

selectquery = 'SELECT image FROM iamgeTable';
data = select(conn,selectquery);
```